# C# How to store a string in an array and convert it to it's Ascii values

Tags: c#, arrays, ascii

I'm pretty new to C# and I'm trying to create a secure login. What I'm trying to do is when a password is entered, the password string will be put in an array of size 8 and each byte of the array will be converted to it's ASCII values and stored copied to the array.

I'm having troubles with errors such as "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'p[]'".

```
  public int hasher(string password, string id)
    {
        int[] p = new int[8];
        int[] a = new int[8];
        p[] = System.Convert.ToInt32(password);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Read the error message again. *Why* does it make sense? Now, consider what the task is in required steps ..

Comment: Note that if this is intended for real-world use (rather than learning), the proper way to implement authentication is to use a system created by experts (e.g., [Asp.Net Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx))

Answer (score 5):

ASCII is `byte` data, not `int`;

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
```

If you really must have integers:

```
int[] bytes = Array.ConvertAll(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password), b => (int)b);
```

Note that if any of `password` is non-ASCII, then you'll get undefined output. For example, `?` in place of some characters.

Comment: Note: If computational speed is of concern, use a for loop of `bytes[i] = password[i]` to avoid lambda/call stack overhead.